# How can I reset my Ubuntu OS after I forgot the encryption password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I put Ubunutu on my computer a few months ago. I used full disk encryption. Well somehow I forgot the encryption pass phrase and so now I can't get into the system at all. I would now like to completely reset the system and put a fresh copy of Ubuntu on it. However, neither my bootable USB stick nor my CD with Ubuntu are recognized when I boot up the system. So I haven't been able to actually overwrite the existing encrypted OS. How can I overcome this and install a fresh copy of Ubuntu?

Comment: On recent computers you have to enter the BIOS to boot on something else than the hard disk.

Comment: What model of computer are you using? This will be helpful so that we can know what UEFI/BIOS options you have available on your system. From there we should be able to determine what you need to set/unset to boot from a Live-USB.

Comment: @Kredns I have a Dell Optiplex 790